# android: OnItemClickListener for multiple Lists

Tags: android, list, listview, onitemclicklistener, onitemclick

Maybe some of you can help me with my problem. I have activity with buttons - Button1 and Button2. Button1 starts Activity1 and Button2 starts Activity2. Both Activities (1 and 2) have the same ListView, and the same Adapter. The difference between it is in List Resources. So Button1 start Activity1 and adding to Listview items "product1" and "product2" (List1). Button2 start Activity2 and adding to the same ListView items "product3" and "product4" (List2). And now I have problem with OnItemClick. It must be the same in both activities too, and it must start Activity3 with ProductDetails. But since OnItemClick works by finding item by position in List - I must add to Activity3 resources of both Lists. Is it possible to do that? I tried to make List3 consist of List1 and List2, and set it to Activity3, but it did not work. Help me please.

Comment: need some clarification, your problem is that you cannot send list of items from adapter to activity 3?, do you want to sen all the items in the list?

Comment: @sai My problem is OnItemClick works if only one list resources exist. When I added List2 resources, and click on Item in Activity2 (where must be "product3" and "product4") - it shows me product1 or product2 details. It's because Activity3 found resources for ProductDetails in List by getting item position. So, that means in Activity3 I must set List with all items (with products 1-4). And I tried to make List 3(addAll List1 and List2). As a result OnItemClick stops to work, it have error.